# In C, if a parent process terminates, then will the child process automatically terminate?

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

If I use `fork()` to spawn a child process, then will the child process automatically terminate once the parent process terminates? Or must this be programmed?

Comment: Why don't you test it? :)

Comment: @Alexander I'm new to C programming and don't yet have the skills to program in this way. It is just a question I was curious about after reading about this functionality. :)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C; it's about the process model on the operating system.

Comment: @GovindParmar Could you please elaborate?

Comment: how is `fork` relevant to C? Is there `fork` in Windows or many other OSes? Could you find `fork` information in C standard?

Comment: This is entirely system specific. On some it will. On others it won't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't really a c question, it's an O/S question.

In Windows, a process will continue until either it calls `ExitProcess` or when it has performed enough CPU RETs that there's nothing left in the call stack.

In Unix, the process will continue and run as a subprocess of `init`.

On both O/S's, a user with enough permissions can kill the process.

Threads, on the other hand, are a different matter-- they will terminate when the process terminates.